# jdbcTemplate error passing args count

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

Strange JDBC TEMPLATE error.

When you perform an update on a table, using the code below, I get the following error:

Org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; Incorrect SQL Grammar [UPDATE adminformulariocontratacao SET statusatual =? WHERE (formulariouuid =?)]; The nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2

```
public void atualizaStatusAtendimentoContratacao(String formulariouuid,String statusGravar) {

    final String query = "UPDATE adminformulariocontratacao "
                      +  "SET statusatual = ? "                             
                      +  "WHERE (formulariouuid = ?)";

    Object argsAtualizaStatus = new Object[] { 
            statusGravar, 
            formulariouuid
        };

    try {
        jdbcTemplate.update(query, argsAtualizaStatus);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        logger.log(Level.ERROR,
                "##ERRO ao Gravar atualização de status do atendimento contratacao:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

When I run the code with as modifications below, it works normally. What's the difference?

```
public void atualizaStatusAtendimentoContratacao(String formulariouuid,String statusGravar) {

    final String query = "UPDATE adminformulariocontratacao "
                      +  "SET statusatual = ? "                             
                      +  "WHERE (formulariouuid = ?)";

    try {
        jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {statusGravar,formulariouuid});
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        logger.log(Level.ERROR,
                "##ERRO ao Gravar atualização de status do atendimento contratacao:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing strange :

from source code :

```
@Override
public int update(String sql, Object... args) throws DataAccessException {
    return update(sql, newArgPreparedStatementSetter(args));
}
```

in case :

> Object argsAtualizaStatus = new Object[] { 
>               statusGravar, 
>               formulariouuid
>           };

type is Object

> Object[] argsAtualizaStatus = new Object[] { 
>               statusGravar, 
>               formulariouuid
>           };

type is array of objects

when you do :

> jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {statusGravar,formulariouuid});

you give correct type - array

in first example you give object , and jdbc template use it as Object not as array of Object

fix :

Object [] argsAtualizaStatus = new Object[] {statusGravar, formulariouuid};

Comment: You really are right. I had no view that I was missing the arguments as an array. My mistake. Thank you!